# (OAuthException - #1) (#1) An error occured while creating the share

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an application that post links to my 2 pages. I have extended access token to never expires and get for each page the correct access token and using a C# application that will use these 2 tokens to post to the pages.

Suddenly one of the pages won't load on my fan and show the latest posts. I got an the error: `(OAuthException - #1) (#1) An error occured while creating the share` while trying to post. Maybe the administrator of the page changes a settings. I started to check the settings of the application. I noticed that the `Sandbox` option is disabled. I enable it; the page started to load well and the application can post links also.

But now the application can post on one page and can't post to the another page. I re-got new tokens and tried to post on the 2 pages, but the same happens(the application can post to the same page that was able to post on the old tokens). I created a new app and also tried to post using the new app, but the same error is happening.

```
(OAuthException - #1) (#1) An error occured while creating the share
```

This error is shown only when trying to post a link. If I try to post a message it will work fine. I tried to post using the graph api explorer (overcoming the case that the C# application is the cause) but the same error is shown on the graph api explorer.

The strange is that it was working well and suddenly stop. I asked the administrator if he changed any settings in the pages or the app itself(although that he is not a developer) but his answer was no.

Is there a missing setting that must be changed?
Is there a way to make it work on the same page because I don't want to loose the big number of likes on the page. What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when your app reached the daily limit of posting that the Facebook platform gives you,, this limit is variable and depends on how the users react with your application,, if they like and comment you get a much bigger daily limit if they hide the post and/or report it your daily limit is decreased and the type of stuff you can publish i also changed and that explains why you can't publish links anymore.